# CRONTAB fail to work

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgresql-12

I have cronjob suddenly fail to work. I have pgdump to execute the following command:

```
pg_dump -h 127.0.0.1 -Fc --dbname=postgresql://postgres:margx@10.100.10.43:5432/db_XP -f /b                                                              ackup-nfs/dump_dbXP_'date +%d-%m-%y'.sql
```

This used to work weeks ago.

The error is about MTA :

```
Dec 13 02:45:01 db-service-train CRON[1606853]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Dec 13 02:55:01 db-service-train CRON[1607374]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
```

Even for simple cronjob like `/bin/echo "test crontab" > /backup-nfs/test_cron.txt`

Gives out the same error:

```
Dec 13 14:56:01 db-service-train CRON[1646850]: (postgres) CMD (/bin/echo "test crontab" > /backup-nfs/test_cron.txt)
Dec 13 14:56:01 db-service-train CRON[1646849]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

What is MTA got to do with the commands? I am not trying to send out any emails.
How can I get rid off this problem?

Comment: What does it have to do with database administration?

Comment: Well, I think it is part of back-up strategy by incorporating an automatic mechanism. I need crontab to work to help me automate the backup process. @mustaccio

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it more of a Linux/Unix problem and not a DBA problem. Consider posting your question on the [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) site. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Cron sends the output of its command to you by email.  Without an MTA, it can't do that.  Which means you can't see what the output is.  If you don't want to install and configure an MTA, then you should redirect the output of your command (both stdout and stderr) to some log file where you can go read it and see what the problem is.

Comment: I have done `pg_dump -h 127.0.0.1 -Fc --dbname=postgresql://postgres:margx@10.100.10.43:5432/db_XP -f /backup-nfs/dump_dbXP_'date +%d-%m-%y'.sql > /backup-nfs/logging.txt >2>&1` but I dont see anything.

Comment: @padjee  `>2>&1` is not valid in my shell.  Maybe you wanted `2>&1`